# Why does plugging my ethernet cable into my PC crash the rest of my internet?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I am trying to connect my PC to my router using an ethernet cable that I have made my self. I have made lots of cables before, and this one also works with other devices, but for some reason when I connect it between my PC and my router my network crashes and I can't access the internet until I unplug the ethernet.

If I use a factory made cable, everything works, but i need a cable that is longer that that which is why I am making my own. I have tested the cable, and it certainly does't seam to be a fault with the cable, so that makes me think it could be the NIC doing something wrong.

There is probably a loop happening somewhere, but I don't think that it is the cable. I am running linux, but using windows has the same problem.

Maybe the NIC is detecting that the router is another PC and therefore acts as a cross over cable causing the loop, but this is strange because other cables work fine.

Any advices very much appreciated.

Comment: I strongly advise you to buy a cable tester if you are going to create your own Ethernet cables.  A decent tester would probably identify the problem.  If I randomly speculate I bet you may have a short or something on the 4-5, or 7-8 pairs.  If your working devices only supported 100mb, they wouldn't use these pairs.  A 1GB device does use these pairs.

Comment: @Zoredache I have a cable tester, and it said that it was all ok. So not too sure why it does't work....

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are just bad cables.

If you like to insist trying to repair the cable, cut the heads off both ends and re-crimp new heads to both ends. Then try the cable again.

Follow one of the color codes shown here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable

Life has all kinds of quirks, and this is one of them that happens with persons involved with connecting cables.

:)

Comment: Well this cable works with other devices. I got a quick question though, does it matter what order the cables are in as long as they are in the same order on each end of the cable?

Comment: Some ethernet devices are something called Auto-MUX, where if you have a straight through or cross-over cable, the port will choose whichever one to use to communicate with the the device on the other end. 

And yes, it dowes matter what order the lines are in on both sides of the cable. Follow the color codes here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable

Comment: so how can I make sure that it just it just goes straight through? Also, why does it matter, surely if the cabled are the same colours at each end so the wired correspond to the correct places it doesn't matter?....

Comment: It matters because of the twists.  The twisted pairs in the cables are there to eliminate noise.  So on a given pair send signal one will be a negative, and a positive  with respect to ground.  By having them be opposite with respect to the ground the electronics can detect and handle some errors caused by EMF interference.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling Each pair is a set, each of the four pairs, have a different twist frequency (twists per inch).

Comment: Ok, I understand. What about the Auto-MUX? How can I make sure that is goes straight through and doesn't cross-over? I really appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Look at the working factory-made cable. You should be able to see the order of the colours at each end, as they are generally made with transparent connectors. Make sure yours are the same. Length should not be a problem: my local supplier has CAT-5E cables up to 50m and CAT-6 up to 30m.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem was. After reading some other treads, suck as [this](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/2792) one, I discovered that sometimes devices do not correctly switch between cross over and straight through, so what I did was chop one of the ends of the ethernet cable and converted it to a [cross-over cable](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ethernet-crossover-cable/).

All works fine now.